# List of Cortex-M4 Opcodes

Tags: arm, opcode, instruction-set, cortex-m

I've been looking for a list of the opcodes used in ARM Cortex M3/M4/M4F, without luck.

There are plenty of [online] references to the 32-bit format of ARM instructions.
References to Thumb-2 instructions are scarce, but [available](http://www.coranac.com/files/gba/re-ejected-thumbref2.pdf).
The version used in -M variants, however, I cannot find!

The ARM Technical Reference Manual has a "programmers Model" section which lists instructions, cycles per instruction... but no actual codes.
I found a "Definitive Guide" which has the same problem.

The information must be out there *somewhere*- you need it to write a compiler.
Where should I be looking?

Comment: If not in the TRM then in the ARM (Architectural Reference Manual) the arm v7-m manual (be it trm or arm) does list every opcode, pseudocode, and which architecture supports that opcode.  you need to just read the manuals better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The ARM Technical Reference Manual [...]

Wrong manual. You need the ARM ARM, or ARM Architecture manual for armv7-m. I cannot link to it here because ARM allows downloads of the ARM ARM only for registered users.

Answer (score 2):

[ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/latest/)